# Action not invoked

Tags: jsp, web-applications, struts2, xml-configuration

The action `reg1` is not called when I click submit button.

My simple struts application is as follows:

`web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee z     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>Struts2</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

`reg.jsp`:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="reg1" >
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"> Password: <input
        type="text" name="password"> Mobile: <input type="text"
        name="mobile"> <input type="submit" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

`struts.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"  
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="reg1.action" class="bean.regbean">
        <result name="success">/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Answer (score 2):

The action is not invoked because it's incorrectly mapped to the url in the form action attribute. Use this action configuration to map the action name, which is used without `.action` suffix.

```
<action name="reg1" class="bean.regbean">
    <result name="success">/login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Also note, that `FilterDispatcher` is deprecated in the latest Struts2 release. So, you have to upgrade and modify [web.xml](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/webxml.html) accordingly.  In the JSP you can use struts tags to bind fields to the bean properties.

Comment: `actionPackages` isn't necessary if you're using XML configuration, which the OP seems to be.

Comment: @DaveNewton Ok, why this init parameter then?

Comment: I assume you're talking about the old `actionPackages` config param for the old CodeBehind plugin, e.g., http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/zero-configuration.html?

Comment: If this parameter related to CodeBehind plugin, why it's in the list of *key initialization parameters* of struts2 filter. Every code where this parameter is used is deprecated.

Comment: Oh, so you're *not* referring to that. Basic point remains: when using XML configuration it's obviously not necessary to specify any packages to scan since they're action classes are explicitly declared in the XML configuration file.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification, sometimes reading docs is not enough to get realized some things previously excluded from the main point of view.

Comment: I don't believe the current docs do an adequate job of explaining many of the config params or how to alter basic framework behavior; unfortunately there aren't many devs working on S2 actively, myself included.

Comment: Yeah, the last line is confusing and completely ignoring without related example of usage ;) I thought they work very actively issuing releases every month.